# Material Icon Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

I am unable to get the material icon to align in the center of the page

It seems to be offset to the left , how can i fix this issue

```
<div class="container-fluid">   
    <div class="msgBox "  >
           <h4>Account verified</h4>
           <span class="material-icons md-36">check_circle_outline</span>
    </div>
</div>
        
CSS

.msgBox {

  padding: 100px;
  border: 5px ;
  text-align:center;
    
}
```

Here is the fiddle;
https://jsfiddle.net/ryan_ramsumair/dyvn2Las/13/

Answer (score 0):

It is actually centered. It is just that icon itself consists of mostly whitespace. [image]

I highlighted the region so you can see it better.

Comment: i see.  I updated the fiddle using fontawesome icon and it lines up center.    https://jsfiddle.net/ryan_ramsumair/dyvn2Las/17/

Comment: @Ryan cool! if my answer is useful, then I would appreciate marking it as correct. :)

Comment: sure but im still looking for a fix that would be responsive across screens, if not ill just have to switch to fontawesome

Comment: What do you mean by responsive across screens? You just have to delete this line of code from your last link: ```<span class="material-icons ">check_circle_outline</span>``` and you are done with the issue you posted in your question.